# Redirect Wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to do a 301 redirection for my wordpress but the name of the directory could change depending on the author of the post and I don't know how to do it.

I need to redirect this:
http://localhost/panamacrea/miembros/XXXXXXXXX/

into this:
http://localhost/panamacrea/miembros/XXXXXXXXX/media/

Any idea?

I already have this in the .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /panamacrea/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /panamacrea/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think it should be something like this but I don't know what should I use instead of XXXXX

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^panamacrea/miembros/XXXXXXXXX/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/panamacrea/miembros/XXXXXXXXX/media/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /panamacrea/miembros/XXXXXXXXX/ http://localhost/panamacrea/miembros/XXXXXXXXX/media/
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but with the XXXXX I meant that the name will change. This is a Buddypress page and every user has his own page. All I need is to redirect them to the subderictory /media/. For example, I'll need to redirect this:

/panamacrea.com/members/exampleuser/

to this: /panamacrea.com/members/exampleuser/media/